# Isn't a DSL another name for an app which solves a particular problem?

Tags: dsl, boo

I am learning boo (got the ebook), but one question I have is what exactly is a DSL? Better question, if a DSL is geared towards a specific problem, then isn't it just another name for really an application space (e.g. Word Processing, DBMS, maths processing software), all solve their own problems.

I ask this because recently a couple of members in a dev team at work wrote an API to test a winforms app and it was deemed a "DSL".

Thanks

Comment: When in doubt, wiki: [Domain-specific language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language). Generally it's not an *application* but a *programming language* or a *framework which extends a language* to aid in solving a particular problem or set of problems. SQL (the query language) is an example of a DSL; the DBMS itself, however, is not a DSL.

Comment: @pst: you should make that comment an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When in doubt, wiki: [Domain-specific language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language)

Generally it's not an application but a *programming language* or a *framework which extends a language* to aid in solving a particular problem or set of problems. SQL (the query language) is an example of a DSL; the DBMS itself, however, is not a DSL.